# Supporting different android TV sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you support multiple screen sizes for android tv? I understand that for smaller devices you can use different layouts for different smallest screen width, but the android docs only mention one screen size bucket for TVs -  how can this account for the vast screen size (and dp) differences between say a 22 inch tv and a 42 inch one? I want the UI to scale so it's  constant for all TV sizes

Comment: I think `Android TV` layouts design with only Two Resolutions as i know.

Comment: So the docs say to layout for 1080p resolution and the system will scale automatically for 720p. But how do I implement based on resolution in layout. For instance, if I wanted a view to be 10dp, would that look smaller on a larger screen, or would to scale automatically?

Comment: I think it will look same on both TV resolution with marginal difference not not more smaller or not more larger. It will with equal criteria.